# **[Err] 1416 : GEOMETRY field in DB Query 

Tags: mysql, database, insert

i want to insert some data to my DB table .
my table called PatientInfo contains columns **PName, DOfBirth, Telephone, Sex**

i've tried this query:
INSERT INTO PatientInfo (PName, DOfBirth, Telephone, Sex) VALUES ('XXXX', 28, 0111000000, 'Female');

but this error appears: 
**[Err] 1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field**

could someone help me on that...

Comment: what are the data types for each field?

Comment: (linestring, int, double, linestring) but there is smth that i have a primary key which is ID but this clmn is "Auto Increment"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LINESTRING data type is for storing spatial data.  The data types for the PName and Sex columns should be a text type; VARCHAR would probably be the best data type for them.