# Yii Framework handling Geospatial data

Tags: php, sql, yii, geospatial, point

I am new to the Yii Framework and I have a database table that stores locations as Geospatial point objects. I am using the code generation tools to generate forms that update/ add to the database. However, these forms don't handle the location field properly. I have been struggling to figure out how this works. The solution mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535245/how-do-i-insert-a-mysql-spatial-point-with-a-yii-model) does not help.

I would appreciate it if anyone could link me to a tutorial on how to handle geospatial point objects within a yii model. I feel like this must be a really easy solution but I cannot seem to get my head around it. The source code for my model, form and controller are provided below:

Model

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "store".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'store':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $location
 */
class Store extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Store the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'store';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('id, name, location', 'required'),
            array('id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, name, location', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'location' => 'Location',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        $criteria->compare('location',$this->location,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

class StoreController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Store;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Store']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Store'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Store']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Store'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Store');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Store('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Store']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Store'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer the ID of the model to be loaded
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Store::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param CModel the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='store-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

form:

```
<?php
/* @var $this StoreController */
/* @var $model Store */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'store-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'name',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'location'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'location'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'location'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

This is a screenshot of what happens when I try to add row to the store table from the auto generated form:

[image: error]

This is expected as a point object has to be constructed from the latitude and longitude. I do not know how to incorporate this into the Yii model.
Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Comment: Can you please clarify "these forms don't handle the location field properly." and also why the method in the other form doesn't work? I see no beforeSave method in your model.

Comment: @AlanHollis Edited question to clarify what I meant. Sorry about the ambiguity.

Comment: Just to clarify, you've tried using the beforeSave method in the model in the previous post, and you get the same error?

Comment: @AlanHollis did add the beforeSave, and yes I get the same error. I removed it before posting on here.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273572/err-1416-geometry-field-in-db-query. It's not Yii error - it's error of wrong using column type `geometry`

Comment: @Sergey: In the question that you linked to me, the guy uses the wrong type. I actually want to use the geometry type for storing a point object.

Comment: @k9ty, He get same error linked with incorrect assign string to GEOMETRY. It's not good. Alter table to change type of column from geomerty to varchar or text

Comment: @Sergey That is my point ! I do not want to use a varchar, i want to use a geometry point object. I need to find a way of inserting this data via yii. I do not want to store latitudes and longitudes as varchar text but as points !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `GeomFromText` with stored procedure in yii:

http://blog.havenisms.com/using-stored-procedures-in-yii